# Display group with minimum average SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, average

I need to create a query which returns the group/s with minimum average value of a column.

Can you please give me an idea on how to do that? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
     Select Groupname,avg(column) as average
        into #temptable
        from tablename
        group by groupname

        Declare @lowvalue INT

        select @lowvalue = top 1 [average] from #temptable order by average

        select * from #temptable where average = @lowvalue

    drop #temptable
```

Comment: I need to display only the group or groups with lowest avg.

Answer (score 0):

The cte will return the average of each group. Then from the cte, select the Minimum of the Averages. Then join both cte's to select groups with minimum average.

```
with cte as (
Select Grp, AVG(Col) as ColAvg 
From MyTable
Group by Grp
), cte2 as (
  select Min(ColAvg) as MinAvg from ate
)   
select a.* from cte as a
outer apply cte2 as b 
Where a.ColAvg = b.MinAvg;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
group, avg(column)
FROM table
GROUP BY group, column
HAVING avg(column) = (
 SELECT TOP avg(column)
 FROM table
 GROUP BY group, column
 order by avg(column)
)
```

Simple but not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the average per group, and then you can calculate the minimum average, and select all groups that have the minimum average. This is a solution with CTE:

```
with avg_per_group as (
select
  grp, avg(val) as avg_val
from
  tablename
group by
  grp
)
select grp
from avg_per_group
where
  avg_val = (select min(avg_val) from avg_per_group);
```

or you can use a window function to calculate the rank (based on the average column) and select all rows that have rank=1:

```
with avg_per_group as (
select
  grp, avg(val) as avg_val
from
  tablename
group by
  grp
),
avg_per_group_rank as (
select
  grp, avg_val, rank() over (order by avg_val) r
from
  avg_per_group
)
select
  grp, avg_val
from
  avg_per_group_rank
where
  r=1;
```

Please see a working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9790c/1).